# python, square finder, memory error

Tags: python, memory-management, perfect-square

I've been working on a problem to find whether or not a given integer `n` is a **perfect square**. Although the algorithm works, I get a `MemoryError`. How should I rephrase this code bit?

Thanks in advance.

```
def is_square(n):    
    for i in range(1, (n/2)):
        i += 1
        if n % i == 0 and n // i == i:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: First, if this is python2, try changing `range` to `xrange`. The former will generate a list of all integers between 1 and n/2 and hold them all in memory.

Comment: Can't tell what is wrong without the input that is causing it. FYI, you only need to check `while i * i <= n` where 'i' starts at 1. Btw why do you increase i by 1 inside the for statement?

Comment: Thanks @eric-appelt, the xrange did the trick!

Comment: @marcadian, I increased i by 1 so that it would start at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Why not have your `range` start at 2? That is the first factor worth checking. Then you won't need a bizarre `i += 1` at the start or your loop.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things:

1. This appears to be Python2 code (since `range(1, n/2)` would throw a `TypeError` in Python3 for all odd `n`s). You should use `xrange` instead of `range` as Eric Appelt suggests in the comments. `range` in Python2 creates a list, when you only really need a generator.
2. You can cut down on the number of operations you're doing by checking if `i * i == n` (or `i**2 == n`). Then you're doing one multiplication (or exponent) and an equality check, instead of a mod, a floordiv, and two equality checks.
3. If you're going that far, why not just do `def is_square(n): root = n**0.5; return int(root) == root`? You'll find that a lot of "improving your algorithms" is leveraging math instead of brute force.

Unrelated, there's no reason to do `i += 1` inside the `for` loop. That's what a `for` loop DOES.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Testing the direct value is a lot faster than testing so many numbers (after all, I'm not looking for factors, just the square)! Also, you're completely on point with #2. Smart, smart!